# Will Different Types of Labels Affect Feature Engineering Outcomes?

Tags: feature-engineering, supervised-learning

Here I would like to limit the question to 2 supervised learning tasks: classification and regression. My question is: for a given set of raw training features, will feature engineering be affected by the type of label/task I choose(binary or continuous labels) and generate different engineered features? If not, does this mean feature engineering process can be independent of labels? In other words, can we just do feature engineering without knowing what the label is?

Answer (score 2):

Different types of labels do affect your feature engineering outcomes and your models outputs.

In a nutshell, binary labeling would give your more feature to select from, while continious labels only provide one. Choosing one or another depends on the amount of available categories, in the possibility of having new ones, and the ML model you´re working on.